# Play music button on global components work for child components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, audio, toggle

i want to know something.

I have a global component, it's a **music-player.vue**, here is the code:

```
    <button class="btn bg-[#a47551] hover:text-gray-50 p-3 shadow-xl"  @click="togglePlayback">
       <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
          {{ isPlaying ? "pause" : "play_arrow" }}
        </span>
    </button>

<script>
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";

export default {
    setup() {
        const audio = new Audio();
        const isPlaying = ref(false);
        
        function togglePlayback() {
            if (isPlaying.value) {
                pausePlayback();
            } else {
                playPlayback();
            }
        }

        function playPlayback() {
            if (!isPlaying.value) {
                audio.play();
                isPlaying.value = true;
            }
        }

        function pausePlayback() {
            if (isPlaying.value) {
                audio.pause();
                isPlaying.value = false;
            }
        }

        function handlePlaybackStart() {
            isPlaying.value = true;
        }

        function handlePlaybackPause() {
            isPlaying.value = false;
        }

        onMounted(() => {
            audio.src = "./../../../assets/song/1.mp3";
            audio.loop = true;
            audio.addEventListener("play", handlePlaybackStart);
            audio.addEventListener("pause", handlePlaybackPause);
        });

        return {
            togglePlayback,
            isPlaying,
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

My question is: I also want to trigger that togglePlayback() button, when i am clicking lihatUndangan button on my **Home.vue**. Here is my code:

```
<button class="btn bg-[#a47551] text-gray-50" @click="lihatUndangan">Lihat undangan</button>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      namaTamu: '',
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const isPlaying = ref(false);
    const audio = new Audio();
    const namaTamu = localStorage.getItem('namaTamu');

    if (!namaTamu) {
      const namaInput = window.prompt('Masukkan nama:');
      
      if (namaInput && namaInput.trim() !== '') {
        localStorage.setItem('namaTamu', namaInput);
        this.namaTamu = namaInput;
      } else {
        this.namaTamu = 'Tamu Undangan';
      }
    } else {
      this.namaTamu = namaTamu;
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isLoading = false;
    }, 500);
  },
  setup() {
    const router = useRouter();

    function lihatUndangan() {
      router.push('/welcome');
    }

    return {
      lihatUndangan
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Can anyone give me a solution or advice? i am new to Vue, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the logic of a component from another component, you can pass a pub/sub object to props. In Home.vue call pubsub.exec(), and in music-player.vue do pubsub.subscribe(()=>... my logic). Or use the regular Vue Provide / Inject approach (https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html)